# Installing Glassfish to work with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, installation

I am stock here with glassfish configuration at Eclipse.
Take a look:

[image]

The finish button is disabled. What should I do here? I am pointing it to the directory in which I have installed glassfish. Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you were trying to register GF 3.1.2 to use Java SE 5.  Java EE 6 requires a Java SE 6 JDK to run successfully.

Comment: Yes I think that might have been the problem since after that I installed a new JDK and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I don't know what was wrong with it. Just tried it one more time and it worked! Sry for taking your times.